# How to break data of columns in multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in which there are some columns with a single value and some columns with multiple values in a string separated by a character '&'.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_data](
[SessionNumber] [float] NULL,
[Patientnumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Operationnumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL) 

INSERT INTO tbl_data([SessionNumber],[Patientnumber],[Operationnumber]) values (3000010815,'0021234360&0010426450','A&B')
INSERT INTO tbl_data([SessionNumber],[Patientnumber],[Operationnumber]) values (3000010816,'0060570630&0077815550&0002201160','C&D&E')
```

I want to get the data in the following way:

```
SessionNumber | PatientNumber | Operatienumber
3000010815    | 0021234360    | A
3000010815    | 0010426450    | B
3000010816    | 0060570630    | C
3000010816    | 0077815550    | D
3000010816    | 0002201160    | E
```

Means splitting it to rows depending on the number of values separated by '&'. I tried it by creating a table-valued function which splits a string in rows by a separator, but I dont know how to use it for multiple columns and multiple rows as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SQL Server 2008 does not have a built in Split-function you might try this:

The trick is to transform your `A&C&E` in `<x>A</x><x>C</x><x>E</x>`.

This can easily be splitted with XML methods.

#### Attention:

If your *real* operation-codes might contain one of the characters `<> or &` you must replace this with `&lt; &gt; and &amp;`

### EDIT new code

This code will create two numbered sub-sets and join them together.

If performance matters there would be a faster approach with a numbers (tally) table to read the elements according to their position in the XML

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_data](
[SessionNumber] [float] NULL,
[Patientnumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Operationnumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL) 

INSERT INTO tbl_data([SessionNumber],[Patientnumber],[Operationnumber]) values (3000010815,'0021234360&0010426450','A&B')
INSERT INTO tbl_data([SessionNumber],[Patientnumber],[Operationnumber]) values (3000010816,'0060570630&0077815550&0002201160','C&D&E');

WITH Splitted AS
(
    SELECT SessionNumber
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Patientnumber,'&','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS CastedPNr
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(Operationnumber,'&','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS CastedONr
    FROM tbl_data
)
,NumberedPN AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SessionNumber ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS PNInx
          ,PNr.value('.','int') AS PNr
          ,SessionNumber AS PNS
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY CastedPNr.nodes('x') AS One(PNr)  
)
,NumberedON AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SessionNumber ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ONInx
          ,ONr.value('.','varchar(max)') AS ONr  
          ,SessionNumber AS ONS
    FROM Splitted
    CROSS APPLY CastedONr.nodes('x') AS One(ONr)  
)
SELECT SessionNumber
      ,p.PNr
      ,o.ONr
FROM tbl_data AS d
INNER JOIN NumberedPN AS p ON d.SessionNumber=p.PNS
INNER JOIN NumberedON AS o ON d.SessionNumber=o.ONS AND p.PNInx=o.ONInx;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but your answer is working fine in case when applying xml only on one column, if I try it on both the columns, it gives incorrect output. [Output](http://i.imgur.com/c89nd2w.jpg) As visible from the output, its cross applying the result of both columns also. I want only 2 rows for first row and 3 rows for 2nd row.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem, although it will become super complicated when I will add more columns to it, but it will work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `split()` function, then you can use `apply`:

```
select d.*, s.*
from tbl_data d outer apply
     dbo.split(d.operationnumber, '&') s;
```

Note:  You should not be storing multiple values in a single column.  You should be using a junction table instead.

Comment: Running this query is giving error 'Table-valued function 'split' cannot have a column alias.' And yes you are right, we should not save the data this way, but its an older system I need to support.

Comment: How can I include PatientNumber also in this query, because again using outer apply on PatientNumber is increasing the rows exponentially.